# Sharepoint Online - REST Call takes almost one minute to complete

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, custom-list

API Call to get all documents to display them in custom list takes about 55 sec to complete and it's irritating to customer that everytime they have to wait such period.

I'm interested into why and what would be approach to make faster performance?

Here's REST API Call:

```
https://mySite.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?top=5000&select=*, FileLeafRef, Author/FirstName, Author/LastName&expand=Author
```

[image]

I believe what causes such poor performance is expanding and getting Author info. Is there a way to get it other way?

Comment: How many total documents are there in the library? Try avoiding `*` in `.select()` the API call, fetch the needed columns only. Also, add indexing on the columns if required. Also, no other way to get the name of person columns (like Author) instead of `expand`. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP there is total of 400 documents in library. Hmm I need atleast 6 of the columns for search.. If I add them in select, I guess the URL will be too big and won't work

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP is there a possibility to do paging? Does the Sharepoint API support it on Sharepoint Online?

Comment: Yes, SharePoint REST API supports paging. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Comment: You should be able to use the 6 column names in API call. Are the [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) for columns too long? Always try to create columns in SharePoint with short and simple names to have easy internal names and then you can rename them to have better display names. Check the recommendations at: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/